# How to have only 1 ListView item active and others disabled in a Xamarin Forms app (android)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms

Having a ListView as below with items that represent `Tasks` with their respective `Status`:

[image: ListView]

The `TasksPage` XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iFacilityMob;assembly=iFacilityMob"
         x:Class="iFacilityMob.TasksPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    ...           
        <ListView 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            x:Name="TasksListView" 
            HasUnevenRows="True" 
            SeparatorVisibility="None" 
            SelectionMode="None" 
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
            Refreshing="TasksListView_OnRefreshing"
            CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <local:TaskCardTemplate></local:TaskCardTemplate>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    ...
</ContentPage.Content>
```

TaskCardTemplate XAML:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="iFacilityMob.TaskCardTemplate">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <Frame x:Name="Frame"
           IsClippedToBounds="True"  
           HasShadow="True"  
           Padding="2,5,5,2"  
           BackgroundColor="White" 
           Margin="10"
           CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Vertical colored bar on the left which indicates the current Status -->
            <BoxView x:Name="BVInitial" Grid.Row="0" Color="Green" IsVisible="{Binding InitialStatus}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="8" Margin="0" CornerRadius="3"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="BVStarted" Grid.Row="0" Color="DarkOrange" IsVisible="{Binding Started}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="8" Margin="0" CornerRadius="3"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="BVPaused" Grid.Row="0" Color="DodgerBlue" IsVisible="{Binding Paused}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="8" Margin="0" CornerRadius="3"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="BVFinished" Grid.Row="0" Color="Black" IsVisible="{Binding Finished}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="8" Margin="0" CornerRadius="3"/>

            <!-- Button Start -->
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BtnStartTask" Text="Start" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Green" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,0,0" HeightRequest="40"   
                    Clicked="BtnStartTask_OnClicked" IsEnabled="{Binding StartEnabledAndVisible}" IsVisible="{Binding StartEnabledAndVisible}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

            <!-- Button Pause -->
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BtnPauseTask" Text="Pause" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,0,0" HeightRequest="40"  
                    Clicked="BtnPauseTask_OnClicked"  IsEnabled="{Binding PauseEnabled}" IsVisible="{Binding PauseVisible}" CommandParameter="{Binding . }"  />

            <!-- Button End -->
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BtnEndTask" Text="End" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Red" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,0,0,5" HeightRequest="40" 
                    Clicked="BtnEndTask_OnClicked" IsEnabled="{Binding EndEnabled}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  />

            ... 
            <!-- The data of each Task, not important in this case -->
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

By clicking the buttons I can change the Status and the view of any `Task` item.

```
private async void BtnStartTask_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    if (btn.CommandParameter is TaskViewModel model)
    {
        // Task
        if (model.ModelType == Enums.ModelType.Task.ToString())
        {
            await _api.UpdateStatus(new StatusUpdateDTO
                {ID = model.ID, ModelType = Enums.ModelType.Task.ToString(), StatusID = (int) Enums.TaskStatus.Started});                    
    }
    else// Ticket
    {
        await _api.UpdateStatus(new StatusUpdateDTO
            { ID = model.ID, ModelType = Enums.ModelType.Ticket.ToString(), StatusID = (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Assigned });
    }

   UpdateView(Enums.Buttons.Start);
}
```

}

```
private void UpdateView(Enums.Buttons buttonPressed)
{
    switch (buttonPressed)
    {
        case Enums.Buttons.Start:
            // Hide Start
            BtnStartTask.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnStartTask.IsVisible = false;

            // Show Pause
            BtnPauseTask.IsEnabled = true;
            BtnPauseTask.IsVisible = true;

            // Enable End
            BtnEndTask.IsEnabled = true;
            BtnEndTask.IsVisible = true;

            BVStarted.IsVisible = true;
            BVFinished.IsVisible = false;
            BVInitial.IsVisible = false;
            BVPaused.IsVisible = false;
            break;

        case Enums.Buttons.Pause:
            ...

        case Enums.Buttons.End:

            ...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that once a `Task` is `Started`, I somehow disable (an overlay and buttons disabled) all the other `Tasks` and eventually re-enable them when the active Task is `Paused` or was `Ended` ?

Edit:

TasksPage ViewModel:

```
public class TaskViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }// TaskID or TicketID 
    public string ModelType { get; set; }// Task or Ticket
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int FloorID { get; set; }
    public string FloorName { get; set; }
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public int? ScheduledTaskID { get; set; }
    public int? ScheduleID { get; set; }

    private int _statusID { get; set; } // Task Status or TicketTask
    public int StatusID
    {
        get => _statusID;
        set
        {
            _statusID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool ActiveItem => (IsTask && (StatusID == (int) Enums.TaskStatus.Started )) || IsTicket && (StatusID == (int) Enums.TicketStatus.InProgress);

    public bool NotActive => !ActiveItem;

    public List<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }

    public bool IsTask => ModelType == ModelTypes.Task.ToString();
    public bool IsTicket => ModelType == ModelTypes.Ticket.ToString();

    public bool StartEnabledAndVisible
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Created || StatusID == (int) Enums.TaskStatus.Paused)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return IsTicket && StatusID == (int) Enums.TicketStatus.Assigned;
        }
    }

    public bool PauseEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Started)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.InProgress;
        }
    }

    public bool PauseVisible
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Started || StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Finished)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.InProgress || StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Closed;
        }
    }

    public bool EndEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Started || StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Paused)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.InProgress || StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Assigned;
        }
    }

    public bool InitialStatus => IsTask && StatusID == (int) Enums.TaskStatus.Created || IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Assigned;

    public bool Started => IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Started || IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.InProgress;

    public bool Paused => IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Paused || IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Assigned;

    public bool Finished => IsTask && StatusID == (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Finished || IsTicket && StatusID == (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Closed;

    public string ProductsLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return Products != null ? string.Join(", ", Products.Select(p => p.Name)) : "";
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And in TasksPage, the parent page:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    _scheduledTasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel>(_schedule.ScheduledTasks.OrderBy(st => st.Finished));
    TasksListView.ItemsSource = _scheduledTasks;
}
```

TasksPage model:

```
public class ScheduleDTO
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }
    public int WorkerID { get; set; }
    public bool OnHoliday { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDatetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StopDatetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LoggedInTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LoggedOutTime { get; set; }
    public string LateReason { get; set; }
    public string EarlyLogoutReason { get; set; }
    public string LateLogoutReason { get; set; }

    // This should be the source for the Listview
    public List<TaskViewModel> ScheduledTasks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When click one start button in cell , you can set selectItem in Model, and set other element be unSelected .Then other button can not be enable . By the way , when binding model using `TwoWay` .( `IsEnabled="{Binding EndEnabled , Mode=TwoWay}"`)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT With your approach i can toggle the state of an individual item, but cant do the same for the rest. The TaskCardTemplate where the update of the Status happens, can access only the current `Task` and not the entire List

Comment: Do you have a try with relating TaskCardTemplate to ViewModel's item or listview's itemselected ?

Comment: Each item is `DataTemplate` and in order to retrieve the item where a button was clicked, i have this:  `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` on each button of a specific DataTemplate

Comment: so when a button is clicked, i can get access to the item object only, but not the entire list

Comment: View model should have two level at least , one level is for listview, another level is  for cell .When cell's property changed , this status can be got and updated the whole model by listview .  You can show View model code , I will check it.

Comment: You should create another model (This viewmodel contained list of TaskViewModel) for listview's itemsource .And when cell's property changed , then can update this model. However here you directly use `new ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel>(_schedule.ScheduledTasks.OrderBy(st => st.Finished));` to listview's itemsource.

Comment: I added also the parent model for `TaskPage` which has some properties not related to the view, but which contains also the `ScheduledTasks` lists that should be the source for the ListView. Not sure what other model do i need ?

Comment: Okey , if having `TaskPage` , no need to create more model. Then when 
one `TaskViewModel` Start status changed , need to notification `TaskPage` to modify other  `TaskViewModel` to change Start status or other property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will advise to put all your view logic in your view models.
It will induce some refactoring, but will be much cleaner and extendable.
Doing so, you just pass a delegate from the TaskPageViewModel to all the TaskViewModel, that will trigger the activation of all the others tasks:

```
public class TaskPageViewModel
{
    IApi _api;

    public TaskPageViewModel(IApi api)
    {
        _api = api;
    }

    List<TaskViewModel> Tasks;

    public void CreateTasks()
    {
        Tasks.Add(new TaskViewModel(OnTaskStatusChanged));

        ...
    }

    private void OnTaskStatusChanged(TaskViewModel selectedViewModel)
    {
        if (selectedViewModel.ModelType == Enums.ModelType.Task.ToString())
        {
            await _api.UpdateStatus(new StatusUpdateDTO
                {ID = selectedViewModel.ID, ModelType = Enums.ModelType.Task.ToString(), StatusID = (int)Enums.TaskStatus.Started});
        }

        var taskStatus = selectedViewModel.Status;
        foreach (var task in Tasks)
        {
            if (selectedViewModel != task)
            {
                task.IsEnable = taskStatus == Status.Pause || taskStatus == Status.End;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TaskViewModel
{
    private readonly Action<TaskViewModel> _onTaskStatusChanged;

    public TaskViewModel(Action<TaskViewModel> onTaskStatusChanged)
    {
        _onTaskStatusChanged = onTaskStatusChanged;
    }

    public ICommand TaskStatusChangedCommand;

    public bool IsEnable;

    public void TaskStatusChanged()
    {
        _onTaskStatusChanged(this);
    }
}
```

Then you just have to bind the StatusChangedCommand as well as the IsEnable property to your buttons and box views.
And you will have all you business logic (api calls) in your parent view model.